# Keras Stateful LSTM for Time series

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am new to the deep learning area and I am trying to make predictions for time series data. I am changing the raw data into sequences of length equal to the look back (as desired) and want to make prediction for the next value. For instance, this is how my data will be (look back=3):

```
   X           Y
[1,2,3]        4
[2,3,4]        5
[3,4,5]        6
```

...... and so on.

To train the lstm model with first sequence [1,2,3] I am doing this:

```
model.fit(X, Y)
```

To get the output for the next value Y, I am doing:

```
model.predict(Y)
```

For this, I am getting error that lstm expects to have 3 dimensions, which I understood that it is because Y doesn't have the same shape as X and lstm is expecting it to be same.

How can I get prediction for the next step while training with one sequence at a time? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to fetch predictions during training time? `model.predict()` is supposed to be called on a sequence, hence `model.predict(X)`

Comment: If I am training with 1st 3 timesteps ([1,2,3]) and want the prediction for next timestep (4), can I give model.predict(X). Didn't we already train the model with X and it's label Y?

Comment: I want to get the predictions for the next timestep for each sequence

Comment: [Time series forecasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series)